# After configure Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on CentOS 8,no matter how i change the Django ,there has no change

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Recently I configure the web server as the guide of this link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7#create-a-python-virtual-environment-for-your-project

I can normally visit the homepage like:
[the normal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVo1g.png)
AND I can normal visit domain_name/admin .

After that ,when i create my_apps,even i change the url this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [

]
```

Once i visit the domain_name or domain_name/admin or IP/admin,there has no change.There has no warning and no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart `gunicorn` after each change, as the automatic reload only happens with you are running the development server, with `manage.py runserver`.

Comment: thank you for your answer,i will have a try. and whether i  need to restart the nginx .

Comment: I have try the way as what you say , and it worker。don't need restart the nginx ,just knock: sudo systemctl restart gunicorn 。thank you so much ,i have spend one day to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manually restart `gunicorn` after each change, you could use **[`reload`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#reload)** in settings, but keep in mind:

> This setting is intended for development. It will cause workers to be
>   restarted whenever application code changes.
>
> The reloader is incompatible with application preloading. When using a
>   paste configuration be sure that the server block does not import any
>   application code or the reload will not work as designed.

Comment: just excuse ,where is the setting file can i setting the gunicorn "reload"

Comment: In your gunicorn service file (e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`), add `--reload` for `ExecStart`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to restart gunicorn automatically each time as already have been noted.

You also may consider using Supervisor or Monit to restart gunicorn automatically, I have such experience with Flask applications.

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/how-can-monit-help-you-manage-your-linux-server.html) for few examples, maybe they will help you.